# MVC4: stored procedure w/multiple parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Using Visual Studio Express 2012, MVC4 web application, and SQL 2008 R2...

I used to have a stored procedure that only accepted one parameter, and when my MVC model included that stored procedure, I could successfully invoke it from my `Controller` and get `Json` results just fine.

Now I have updated the stored procedure to accept two parameters.  I've refreshed my MVC model but am unable to invoke the stored procedure correctly from my controller when passing two parameters.

**Here is my old stored procedure and controller using one parameter (this works):**

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDependencyNodes]     
@CISearchString nvarchar(100)
```

**Old Controller:**

```
namespace CMDB.Controllers
{
public class GoJSDiagramNodesAndLinksController : Controller
{
   private CMDBEntities db = new CMDBEntities();
   public ActionResult GetDependencyNodes(string CISearchString)
    {
        return Json(db.GetDependencyNodes(CISearchString).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
}
```

**Here is my new stored procedure and controller accepting two parameters:**

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDependencyNodes]
@CISearchString nvarchar(100),
@ExcludeString nvarchar(100)
```

**New Controller:**

```
namespace CMDB.Controllers
{
public class GoJSDiagramNodesAndLinksController : Controller
{
   private CMDBEntities db = new CMDBEntities();
   public ActionResult GetDependencyNodes(string CISearchString, string ExcludeString)
    {
   return Json(db.GetDependencyNodes(CISearchString, ExcludeString).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
}
```

In Visual Studio Express 2012, I get an error on my "return Json" line stating:

'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could not be found.

If I change the line from:

```
return Json(db.GetDependencyNodes(CISearchString, ExcludeString).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

to:

```
return Json(db.GetDependencyNodes(CISearchString, ExcludeString).ToString().ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The error goes away but the controller returns a -1 instead of the correct Json results.  I've tested the stored procedure in SQL Manager and can see the expected results.

Here is partial code from my file CMDBModels.Desginer.cs with GetDependencyNodes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cISearchString">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    /// <param name="excludeString">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
    public int GetDependencyNodes(global::System.String cISearchString, global::System.String excludeString)
    {
        ObjectParameter cISearchStringParameter;
        if (cISearchString != null)
        {
            cISearchStringParameter = new ObjectParameter("CISearchString", cISearchString);
        }
        else
        {
            cISearchStringParameter = new ObjectParameter("CISearchString", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        ObjectParameter excludeStringParameter;
        if (excludeString != null)
        {
            excludeStringParameter = new ObjectParameter("ExcludeString", excludeString);
        }
        else
        {
            excludeStringParameter = new ObjectParameter("ExcludeString", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction("GetDependencyNodes", cISearchStringParameter, excludeStringParameter);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The compiler doesn't lie - GetDependencyLinks is returning an integer, which I assume is the root of the issue.

Comment: Does it appear that my syntax for calling the stored procedure "GetDependencyLinks" is correct when passing two parameters?  I'm not sure why changing this from one to two parameters would cause ToList() to give this error.

Comment: It's impossible to tell how you're actually passing the parameters to the Stored Procedure, because that is *actually* being done by the GetDependencyLinks method.  Can you post the code in the GetDependencyLinks method?

Comment: I made a mistake and copied into my original message the wrong stored procedure. Through the message, it should have been GetDependencyNodes.  I've edited the message.

Comment: I've also edited my original message to include the GetDependencyNodes method at the bottom.

Comment: You got me looking at the old and new Designer.cs files and I'm noticing that the auto-created file changed the methods from ObjectResult to Int for all of my stored procedures with two parameters instead of one.  I have a total of 7 stored procedures, 4 of which use two parameters.  All 4 of those now have "public int" instead of "public ObjectResult".  I wonder why it chose to create them that way when I re-created my model.  I'll try to look into that.

Comment: This seems to be my issue.  Not sure why my model is being created this way when my stored procedure has two parameters instead of one.  My model is being created from the database.  I'm trying to apply update 1 for Visual Studio Express 2012 now to see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Installing update 1 for Visual Studio Express 2012 did not fix my issue.  I'm stumped as to why it is deciding to make my method 'int' instead of 'ObjectResult'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things first move your Data Access to another class, keep your controller as light as possible.

Next map your stored procure output to an basic class that has properties that match the returned columns (entity class)

this should let you look at the returned data in debug a lot easier and is just good programming practice